# Is there any way to change callback timeout in tornado PeriodicCallback instance?

Tags: python, tornado

I know about:

`periodical_cllback_instance.stop()
periodical_cllback_instance.start()`

but it restarts with current `callback_time` ... is there any monkey patch to change `callback_time` after triggering `stop()` ... or some other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the `callback_time` directly, you don't even need to stop the `PeriodicCallback` instance. This snipped seems to work for me:

```
import tornado
from tornado.ioloop import PeriodicCallback

pc = None
counter = 0


def get_periodic_callback():
    global pc
    if pc is None:
        pc = PeriodicCallback(callback, 1000)
    return pc


def callback():
    global counter
    if counter < 5:
        counter += 1
        print("foo")
    else:
        pc = get_periodic_callback()
        pc.callback_time = 100
        print("bar")


pc = get_periodic_callback()
pc.start()
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```